# Whats the meaning of 'static' when declaring a function

Tags: php, class

this is the code from the tutorial book.

```
class user {
    // return if username is valid format
    public static function validateUsername($username){
        return preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9]{2,20}$/i', $username);
    }
}
```

i wonder, what is the function of static?

it's too bad the book i read didn't explain it :(

Comment: Pedantic note:  That's a method, not a function (I know it still uses the `function` keyword, but it's a method since it's bound to a class)...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The end result is that you don't need to create an instance of the class to execute the function (there's more to it than that, but I'll let the manual cover those parts):

[PHP: Static Keyword - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

In your example, you would call your function like:

```
user::validateUsername("someUserName");
```

Rather than having to create an instance and then calling the function:

```
$user = new user();
$user->validateUsername("someUserName");
```

Comment: I would vote for this answer, but it means much more than that.

Comment: @NickLarsen - Re-worded things a bit to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

> Static methods and variables are
>   useful when you want to share
>   information between objects of a
>   class, or want to represent something
>   that's related to the class itself,
>   not any particular object.

source: http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/495206-static-method-vs-non-static-method

Answer (score 0):

Static functions are functions belonging to the class and not the object instance. They can be called without instancing the class by referring to it directly -

```
user::validateUsername(...);
```

Or using the `self` keyword from inside the class

```
self::validateUsername(...);
```

Static function are global functions in a way. You should use those sparingly as dependencies on static functions are harder to extract and make testing and reuse more difficult.

Read more in the PHP manual - [the static keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)